# Is there a way to add 2 or more zip code boundaries together to form territories?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I want to create a territories map on Google Maps that follows zip code boundaries but have some of my territories include multiple zip codes. I was wondering if there is a way to do this by listing which of google's pre-mapped zip code boundaries (with the hope that Google has a zip code boundary list to pull from?) I would like to combine in each group.

For example:

```
Territory A:
    84000,
    84001,
    84002,
    etc.
```

Then have,

```
Territory B:
    84108,
    84101,
    84115,
    etc.
```

And so on covering the entire USA.

Any tips or advice would be great. I'm looking to use pre-defined  boundaries so it will be easier to update and any zip code changes country-wide will automatically be accounted for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's Zip Code Boundaries are not available through the API or for download or any other mechanism. That is solely a feature of maps.google.com. To do this, you would have to source the data yourself. There are a number of companies that do this, just search on zip code boundaries download. The US Census provides something called a [Zip Code Tabulation Area](http://www.census.gov/geo/ZCTA/zcta.html), which is not the same but related and potentially useful.